# Odd behavior with timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timestamp, nsdate

I'm seeing an odd behavior with trying to get seconds since epoch in objective C.  This:

```
NSString *nowTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
                             [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Outputs 15907296, when the current timestamp should be 1243555623 (05/28/2009 @ 7:08pm EST).  The system time on the iPhone is correct.  I can't figure out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

timeIntervalSince1970 returns an NSTimeInterval, which is a typedef for double; %d is not the right formatter to print a double (you want %f).

Answer (score 5):

As the return from `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];` is a double, you could try this:

```
NSString *nowTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
                         [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the result from `NSDate` is a decimal int? The docs say it is a double.  You could try casting.

Also, sometimes you will get a pointer value back instead of the actual value, if something is a `NSNumber` under the covers, you may need to use `intValue`, or `doubleValue` to get the actual content of what is at the address.